# How to python pandas.DataFrame.fillna(method='pad') left to right?

Tags: python, pandas

Title says it all, method=pad goes from top to bottom (vertical axis), but I would like to pad from left to right (horizontal axis). Should I just rotate the table?

For example, I need the value in column A to update the NaN value in column B and so on. This works with rows, but not columns?

I didn't find anything in the documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: even with `axis=1` it doesn't work?

Comment: That totally works. I'm sorry, I think I need to go back and understand the fundamentals a little better. Thanks again.